# Dropdown list from db, how to combine columns for DataTextField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a dropdown list that gets populated from a datatabase. I have it working when wanting to display only the firstname in the DataTextField of the dropdown. But if i want to display 2 fields, firstname and lastname, then it throws an error. Why is this not working or how can i get it to work?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_customers", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
con.Open();
da.Fill(ds, "Customers");
CustomerList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
CustomerList.DataTextField = "FirstName" + " " + "LastName";
CustomerList.DataValueField = "CID";
CustomerList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to select the "virtual" column from the database:

```
string sql = @"SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName, 
                      CID, FirstName, LastName  
               FROM tbl_customers 
               ORDER BY FullName ASC;"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
// ...
CustomerList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
CustomerList.DataTextField = "FullName";
CustomerList.DataValueField = "CID";
CustomerList.DataBind();
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter: If I can't make a query like that and I want to join the column in the control. How can I do it?  <asp:DropDownList                             runat="server"
                            ID="drpMembers"
                            DataTextField="InsuredsFullName" + "OTHERFIELD"
                            DataValueField="Id"
                            >

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to define a custom column:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS [FormattedName] FROM tbl_customers", con);
```

Then you can bind directly to that column:

```
CustomerList.DataTextFIeld = "FormattedName";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use database replicate method while joining the columns for the equal spacing..

```
 string sql = @"SELECT FirstName + replicate(' ', 20 - len(FirstName)) + LastName AS FullName, 
                          CID, FirstName, LastName  
                   FROM tbl_customers 
                   ORDER BY FullName ASC;"
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    CustomerList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
CustomerList.DataTextField = "FullName";
CustomerList.DataValueField = "CID";
CustomerList.DataBind();
```